# /dev/urandom to provide random addresses to mmap()

Tags: c, linux, posix

I keep getting the same address locations after calling the function 4 times even though I am using /dev/urandom. Why is that ? Why is /dev/urandom providing very low numbers or very high ones?

```
104
0x7fffb128de78
0x7f9e3c565000
4294967192
0x7fffb128de78
0x7f9e3c564000
97
0x7fffb128de78
0x7f9e3c563000
4294967139
0x7fffb128de78
0x7f9e3c562000
```

```
void test(void){
    char random[4];
    int filedescriptor = open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY);
    read(filedescriptor, random, 4);
    close(filedescriptor);

    unsigned int hintmemoryaddress = (unsigned int)random;
printf("%u\n", hintmemoryaddress);

    char *p = (char *)hintmemoryaddress;
    p += hintmemoryaddress;
printf("%p\n", &p);

    char *x = (char *)mmap((void *)&p, 1000, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
printf("%p\n", x);
}

int main(void){
    test();
    test();
    test();
    test();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're confusing the value of a pointer with its address. You want to use `p`, not `&p`. Further, the temp char array is useless, and your copying it to around is all incorrect. The corrected code should be:

```
void test(void){
    void *p;
    int filedescriptor = open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY);
    read(filedescriptor, &p, sizeof p);
    close(filedescriptor);

    char *x = (char *)mmap(p, 1000, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    printf("%p\n", x);
}
```

Comment: I have added to your code. mmap() will ignore a 8 byte (64 bit) memory address because it is currently not possible to have 2^64 RAM. 4 bytes must be zeroed so mmap() will apply the hint.

Comment: @elaine: The address passed to `mmap` is supposed to be just a hint, unless `MAP_FIXED` is used, so I find it odd that the kernel can't fix it up to match whatever requirements it has. However, it should not be necessary to do this at all. The kernel *automatically* randomizes `mmap` locations to some extent, and use of nonzero addresses with `mmap` is nonportable.

Comment: It seems the code I added was removed by peer review. All I can say is to test it. Without my edit, mmap() will ignore the hint on 64 bit systems; with my code, mmap() will use it. (I am using Debian wheezy Linux x64 on a 4GB RAM desktop computer.)

Comment: I think the edit was rejected not for the content, but because editing an answer rather than discussing what's wrong in the comments is considered inappropriate on this site. Non-author edits should generally be reserved for fixing typos or obvious misstatements, fixing the formatting (not content), removing off-topic offensive comments, or in the case of really bad answers with harmful advice, adding an "editor's note" that the advice is harmful. If the answer is just incomplete or you think it needs changing, the comments are the right place to discuss that.